# Magento 2: How to Extend core js files or class or function?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I need to extend core js in my module or theme in this case how to do it,

I can achieve it by keeping the complete file in my theme and do the changes, in this case, we will lose updates and if we update Magento then my website will break

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

We can extend the core js in below way

Create a requirejs-config.js in MYMODULE/view/frontend

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/gallery/gallery': {
                'NAMESPACE_MYMODULE/js/gallery_brand_logo': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then create  gallery_brand_logo.js in

code\NAMESPACE\MYMODULE\view\frontend\web\js\gallery_brand_logo.js

```
define(['jquery','mage/utils/wrapper'], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function (initialize) {
        return wrapper.wrap(initialize, function (initialize, config, element) {
            // my code before

            initialize(config, element);    

            // my code after
            //brand log
            if(config.brandlog){            
                $('.fotorama__nav-wrap').css('display', 'block');               
                $('.fotorama__nav-wrap').addClass('fotorama__nav-wrap--vertical');

                $('.fotorama__nav').before('<div style="border: 1px solid red;color: red;height: 70px;" class="brandlog"><img src="'+config.brandlog+'" /></div>');             
            }   
            //brand log end
        });
    };
});
```

Note :- In above I used custom option brandlog, pass this value in product/view/gallery.phtml so i extend product/view/gallery.phtml also and

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "brandlog": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $logopath; ?>",
                .
                .
                .
```

Comment: do you get encounter with no template warning before? I mixins core `Magento_Catalog/js/product-gallery` widget for my custom js and everytime i call it. Firebug show warning **No template was found by selector: null**. Of course my script not running. I Already check entire template html

Comment: Have you resolved the No template was found by selector: null issue ?

Comment: Have you an idea about how to override _calcProductPrice function in custom scripts.js file (using mixins)?

Answer (score 1):

in some case js class as more then one function at that time you can not follow below answer

if you want to extend the specific function follow below code

i just extend the shipping address validation at the time of checkout

```
/**
 * @author pradeep.kumarrcs67@gmal.com
 */
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($,quote) {
    'use strict';
console.log("Called this Hook.");

     return function(targetModule){
        //if targetModule is a uiClass based object
        return targetModule.extend({
            validateShippingInformation:function()
            {
                console.log("validateShippingInformation.");
                 this.errorValidationMessage('Pradeep.');
                 //return false;

                 var result = this._super(); //call parent method
                    //do your new stuff
                return result;
            }
        });
        };

});
```